# Render partial scaffold in the index view - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want exibe the action 'Show' of scaffold in my index using ajax but when i click in show dont appear nothing my files is:

finances_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @finance = Finance.find(params[:id])

  end
```

_show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Date update:</b>
  <%= @finance.updated_at %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Money:</b>
  <%= @finance.money %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Entrance:</b>
  <%= @finance.entrance %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Description:</b>
  <%= @finance.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Situation:</b>
  <%= @finance.situation %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Local:</b>
  <%= @finance.local %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_finance_path(@finance) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', finances_path %>
```

my
index.html.erb modified the button show:

```
Bem vindo <%= session[:user_name]%>
<div id='list' align='left'>
<h1>Finanças - Hoje é dia <%= Date.today %></h1>
<%= link_to 'New Finance', new_finance_path %>
<table  cellpadding="5"  >
  <tr>
    <th>Data de Inserção</th>
    <th>Caixa</th>
    <th>Entrada</th>
    <th>Descrição</th>
    <th>Situação</th>
    <th>Local</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @finances.each do |finance| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= finance.created_at %></td>
    <td><%= finance.money %></td>
    <td><%= finance.entrance %></td>
    <td><%= finance.description %></td>
    <td><%= finance.situation %></td>
    <td><%= finance.local %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', finance,:action => 'show',:id => @finance , :remote =>:true %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_finance_path(finance) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', finance, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
</div>
<div id='tools' align='right'>
    <%if @finance %>
        <%= render('show') %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to 'Logout', new_session_url,method: :delete %>
```

when i click in the show appear the url 'localhost:3000/finances/1' but dont happening nothing when i click this i want click and show my partial 'show' in the same page, i render the partial 'show' if especified the @finance ,

```
   <%if @finance %>
        <%= render('show') %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `= render 'finances/show'`